# The resource cannot be found. Getting resource error with .attr jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC website which is causing issues related to resource path.

I was using `Localhost` for path earlier but now I am using `Route` for all views. Now everything working fine but I am getting issue to set report path.

Display Report

This button  is on View InvoiceReport.  And this is the function.

```
function ShowReport() {

  if ($('#InvoiceID').val() == '') {
        alert("Please search the record and then select grid row");
        return;
    }
    else if ($('#InvoiceID').val() == '0') {
        alert("Please search the record and then select grid row");
        return;
    }
    else {
        ShowLoading();
        $('#frameReport').attr('src',"Report.aspx?InvoiceID=" + $('#InvoiceID').val());
        $('#divframe').show();
        selectTab1(2);
        HideLoading();
    }

}
```

The element `frameReport` is an iframe and looks as follow:

```
<div id="divframe" 
   style="padding: 40px 40px 40px 110px; float: left; margin-top: 30px;
   display: none"
> 
  <iframe id="frameReport" src="" width="900px" height="940px"></iframe>
</div>
```

The report is a normal .aspx page which is outside this views. It was working earlier when I was just using relative paths like `localhost://`.

But now when I am clicking on the "Report" button it is retaining on same path.

```
http://192.168.1.100/InvoiceReport/Index
```

But it should need to redirect to this url that I am passing in .attr.

```
 Report.aspx?InvoiceID='123'
```

Please give your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, It's a little unclear here whats going on and I'm trying to work out if the issue relates to routing or your JS . When you navigate to /Report.aspx?InvoiceID=123 what happens?

Comment: @LiamB  on  InvoiceReport/Index  there is a report button when i am clicking on report button it should redirect to Report.aspx?InvoiceID='123'   but its retaining  only on same  this url.   /InvoiceReport/Report.aspx

Comment: Can you show us your Javascript (The button click function)

Comment: @LiamB  i edited the question.please check now.

Comment: What is #frameReport ? A button or something else ?

Comment: its Iframe.     <div id="divframe" style=" padding: 40px 40px 40px 110px; float: left; margin-top: 30px; display: none">
                    <iframe id="frameReport" src="" width="900px" height="940px"></iframe>
                </div>

Comment: @user1638889 that is not an `iframe`! An `iframe` will be dined as follows: `<iframe src=""></iframe>`. This element is created for including external page into an existing page, while `<div>` is create a html snippet.

Comment: @reporter  its inside div.please check.

Comment: My fault, sorry. And you are sure that the created url was correct created?

Comment: @reporter  its working when i am adding hardocded it.

Comment: @user1638889 Have you tried to call the website with generated URL? I mean, copy the generated and append url into the clipboard, open a new tab or window and paste it into this

Comment: @reporter   adding  /  in front solve my problem.Thanks for your valuable time.